# Why it is not possible call a function inside a while loop in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

i'm trying to use a while loop to call a function n times. I have made a simple example that return this error "Warning 10: this expression should have type unit."

```
let max a b =
if a > b then a else b
;;

let i = ref 0;;

while !i <= 5 do

(* function that is called i times *)
max 2 !i ;

i := !i + 1;

print_int !i

done;;
```

How can i call a function using while or for loop n times?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's only a warning, and it has nothing to do with the loop. It is merely pointing out that you are calling a function but ignoring its result. Usually, such a situation is an unintended bug. In the case of your example, the call to `max` is indeed useless.

If you want to have it nevertheless and silence the warning, you can be explicit about ignoring the result by doing

```
ignore (max 2 !i)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Why the result of the function is ignored? I would expect it to print the result of the function that I recall

Comment: @bryan1991 If you want to print the result, replace `ignore` with a call to `print_int` or `Printf.printf "%d\n"`. Outside of the REPL, OCaml (like most languages) doesn't print the result of expressions unless you tell it to. And in the REPL it still only prints the result of the whole expression, not every subexpression.